# SharePoint 2013 formula to look between 2 date fields based on if one is blank

Tags: date, sharepoint, calculated-field

I am attempting to create a formula for a calculated field in a SharePoint 2013 list. The field where the formula is to be added will display the date from a 2nd field, unless that field is blank. If blank, the formula looks to a 3rd field and uses that date. Below is a written example and the formula I wrote, but doesn't work.

Field 1 displays date appearing in Field 2. If Field 2 is Blank, the date in Field 3 is displayed.

```
=[Field 2], IF(ISBLANK=([Field 3]))
```

Any help with correcting my formula is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

If filed 2 is blank, show field 3, else show field 2

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Field 2]),[Field 3],[Field 2])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. I have been struggling with all day.